# Excel Macro: Run-time Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I am making an Excel Macro, but keeps getting Run-time error 1004: on this piece of code.

```
FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(""VLOOKUP(""(Active.Workbook.Sheets(""Sheet1(CT)"").Range(""E2"")),Application.Goto Workbooks(""Cycle time list of products.xls"").Sheets(""Sheet1"").Range(""A1:C300"")"",""3"",""FALSE"")"",0)"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run-time error 1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652537/run-time-error-1004)

Answer (score 4):

you have way too many `"` and you are not properly concatenating the formula with vba:

```
.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1(CT)").Range("E2").Address(0,0,,1) & "," & Workbooks("Cycle time list of products.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C300").Address(1,1,,1) & ",3,FALSE),0)"
```

Comment: Alternatively use sheet names in the formula directly: `Selection.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Sheet1(CT)'!$E$2,'[Cycle time list of products.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1:$C$300,3,FALSE),0)"`

Comment: So I did this and now is says: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: @Mads.R Check the sheet names and workbook names as spelled correctly.

Comment: Also this assumes that the workbook `"Cycle time list of products.xls"` is open.  If it is closed then you will need to open it. @Mads.R